# Recursive Caching Based Fibonacci

Tags: c, algorithm, caching, fibonacci

I am trying to implement caching based Fibonacci sequence. But it gave me the wrong output for example (fibcache(8) gave me an answer of 13 instead of 21. However in some cases it gave me the correct output. For example fibcache(6) gave me 8. Cant figure out whats wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DCACHE_SIZE 5

int fibcache(int number);
long cacheodd[DCACHE_SIZE] = {0};
long cacheeven[DCACHE_SIZE] = {0};
int i_odd, i_even;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int fibNum = fibcache(6);

    printf("The Fibonacci number is %d\n", fibcache(fibNum));

}

int fibcache(int n)
{
    int result;

    if (n == 0) 
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
     return 1;

    if(n%2==0)
    {
        if (cacheodd[i_odd] != 0) 
            result = cacheodd[i_odd];
        else
        {
            cacheodd[i_odd] = fibcache(n-1) + fibcache(n-2);
            result = cacheodd[i_odd];
        }
    }
    else
    if(n%2==1)
    {
        if (cacheeven[i_even] != 0) 
            result = cacheeven[i_even];
        else
        {
            cacheeven[i_even] = fibcache(n-1) + fibcache(n-2);
            result = cacheeven[i_even];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should really learn how to use a debugger :)

Comment: Am new in C. Learning to use a debugger is in my to do list though :)

Comment: @xTiraMissU use print statements :)

Comment: hint: what values do `i_odd` and `i_even` take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems:

- You actually print `fib(fib(6))`, a much larger number than `fib(6)`.
- Your caching function is too complicated: why handle even and odd numbers differently?  You should make a special case of numbers larger than the cache size and verify if the cached value has been computed.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DCACHE_SIZE 5

long fibcache(int number);
long fibcache_values[DCACHE_SIZE] = { 0 };

int main(void) {
    printf("List of Fibonacci numbers:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
        printf("    fib(%d) = %ld\n", fibcache(i));
    }
    return 0;
}

long fibcache(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    if (n < DCACHE_SIZE) {
        if (fibcache_values[n] != 0)
            return fibcache_values[n];
        else
            return fibcache_values[n] = fibcache(n - 1) + fibcache(n - 2);
    } else {
        return fibcache(n - 1) + fibcache(n - 2);
    }
}
```